# How to properly map MyBatis parent relation?

Tags: oracle, mapping, mybatis

I'm currently struggling on trying to map my class using MyBatis and Oracle database.

I have a table with columns ID, CODE, DESCRIPTION, PARENT, VALUE, UNITS

I have a model:

```
public class Parameter {

  private String code;
  private String description;
  private String value;
  private Parameter parent;
  private String units;

 <...>
}
```

and a xml mapper parameterMapper.xml:

```
<resultMap id="ParameterResultMap" type="Parameter">
    <id property="id" column="id" />
    <result property="code" column="code" />
    <result property="description" column="description" />
    <result property="value" column="value" />
    <result property="units" column="units" />
    <association property="parent"
        resultMap="persistence.ParameterMapper.ParameterResultMap"
        columnPrefix="parent_" />
</resultMap>

    
<select id="readParameter" parameterType="Parameter" resultMap="ParameterResultMap">
    SELECT
        p.id,
        p.code,
        p.description,
        p.value,
        p.units,
        par.id AS parent_id,
        par.code AS parent_code,
        par.description AS parent_description,
        par.value AS parent_value,
        par.units AS parent_units
    FROM parameter p
    LEFT JOIN parameter par ON par.code = p.parent
</select>
```

And I get  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection does not contain value for persistence.ParameterMapper.ParameterResultMap] exception on my console.
What I've done wrong and where could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the association references the same result map, just use the short name i.e. `<association property="parent" resultMap="ParameterResultMap" columnPrefix="parent_" />`.